# Add-on for automatic URL shortening in browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons, plugins, firefox-extensions

Are there any plugins or third party apps/add-ons/extensions in Firefox, Chrome, or any other browser which shortens copied URLs on the go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the bookmarlet for bit.ly (a URL shortening service):

> https://bitly.com/pages/tools

There's also a Firefox add-on for previewing shortened URLs:

> http://bit.ly/firefox-extension

You could also try Shorten URL - a Firefox add-on that shortens URLs for many other shortening services:

> https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shorten-url/

Comment: Thanks! but the FF add-on doesn't work in 4.0.1 version

Comment: Added another FF add-on which covers many different URL shortening services- see main text.